# How to use zsh instead of bash in laradock using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I'm in my laradock folder and after running `docker-compose up -d apache2 mysql phpmyadmin` I run `docker-compose exec workspace bash` but bash is not aesthetically pleasing.

So I wanted to use zsh instead, I tried `docker-compose exec workspace zsh` hoping that would work but it gave me this error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:337: starting container process caused "exec: \"zsh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

How can I use zsh instead of bash in laradock with docker-compose?

Answer (score 2):

1.Make sure zsh is installed in the container, by using command:

`docker-compose exec -it workspace bash
(then inside container)
zsh`

If it is not changing its shell to zsh, then u may have to install zsh by:
(For Ubuntu, base image):

`apt-get update;
apt-get install zsh;`

Then run "zsh".

For doing these changes while build:
Add the below commands to your Dockerfile:

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install zsh
RUN PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/zsh"`

then do, 

`docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d`

Now try docker-compose exec workspace zsh, it works.